# Why does an AC current cause a resonator to vibrate?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, low-temperature-physics

This is an experiment I'm going to be doing, and I can't quite get my head around it.

The experiment is performed at very low temperatures to investigate the properties of superfluids. There's a circular resonator (made of aerogel) in a vertical magnetic field. An AC current gets passed through wires that are attached horizontally to the resonator. That causes it to move perpendicular to both the field and wires of course, because of the Lorentz force. The drive frequency gets changed to find resonance.

We measure the 'voltage in phase with the driving frequency'. When this is maximium, and the 'out of phase voltage' is minimum, that's a resonance. What exactly are these two quantities? What is it that's being measured when you measure 'in phase voltage'? Out of phase voltage should be zero but the lab manual says it'll never actually be zero and we have to set a zero point. Why? And what's meant by 'resistive background' to in phase voltage?

Comment: Is this a magnetic resonance experiment? I think that in order to provide an answer some more detail is required.  For example it is not clear which voltage you are measuring.

Comment: @Farcher I'm not sure - we're measuring 'in phase voltage' and I don't know what that means. I have a vague idea that it's the voltage generated by the AC current plus some contribution from induced emf - does that sound plausible?